# Using RPi4 as a USB OTG slave devixe

Tags: pi-4

I bought an old pickup and I’m planning on doing a big upgrade on it featuring a touchscreen that’s connected to a RPi4 that listens to (and controls) various electronics in the car. The electronics side isn’t the issue here as I basically know how to process the 12 v analog signals to be readable by the 3.3 v interface RPi. If all else fails I’ll use a bunch of picos as ADC’s and feed their digital output to the RPi.

I looked at what are the options and found out that it’s probably cheaper for me just to use an android tablet as a master device and code an interface for it that communicates with the RPi as a slave device via USB OTG.

What would my options be? Is there a ready library available and is there a decent tutorial or even documentation (or well commented source code) for it?

Comment: An issue here may be that the Android tablet will not put out enough current -- only the USB-C port can be used as a slave, and it will draw power as well, and pretty sure trying to power it from the breakout and the port is a bad idea.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.